# Writing Generic wrapper APIs for backend APIs

Tags: node.js, api, express

I have a few backend APIs which starts with /companies .
Exa. (there are more than 30 APIs)

GET: https://example.com/api/companies/employee

GET: https://example.com/api/companies/sites

POST: https://example.com/api/companies/addNewSite

PUT: https://example.com/api/companies/updateSite

I need to pass Authorization header to all these APIs. For that I need to write a wrapper API and use that API to access from the client side.

To achieve this, I understand I need to create different routes for all above APIs in my node.js express application something like this:

```
app.get("/api/companies/employee, (req, res) => {
   req.header = {authorization: "Bearer sometoken"};
   const response = await apiHelper.makeRequest("GET", https://example.com/api/companies/sites);
   res.status(200).json(response);
})

app.post("/api/companies/addNewSite", (req, res) => {
  ....
})
```

This way, I need to create wrapper APIs for all 30 different APIs which doesn't seems right.

So, was wondering if there is a better way to create one single wrapper API for all above APIs.

Comment: I think you basically want to have an API Gateway. Of course you can build a node.js - epxress application. You might check out different already out the box solutions as well, like AWS API Gateway or https://www.express-gateway.io/.

Comment: @SándorBakos express-gateway seems need a static key... i am looking for a gateway which can actually sing the jwt key and pass to the external api...